# Reverse checkbox value so that checked is false in the model

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a Kendo TreeView where I need to invert the visual presentation of the checkboxes. So the value false would result in a checked checkbox.

The reason for this is that the treelist is listing a bunch of items that should be excluded. So when they check something it's excluded. That isn't terribly intuitive.

Changing the logic behind saving this exclude list is really something I'd like to avoid. Instead I'd rather just change the visual presentation of the data. So that `checked=false` would result in a checked checkbox and the opposite.

Here's what I'm working with

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("Tree")
    .Checkboxes(c => c.Name("Checked"))
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewModel>)ViewBag.Tree, mappings =>
    {
        mappings.For<TreeViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, vm) =>
        {
            item.Id = vm.Id.ToString();
            item.Text = vm.Name;
        })
        .Children(vm => vm.Children));
    });
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "Checked" property based on the passed item as follows:

```
  mappings.For<TreeViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, vm) =>
    {
        item.Id = vm.Id.ToString();
        item.Text = vm.Name;
        item.Checked = vm.Checked ? false : true;
    })
```

Comment: That's pretty clever :)

Comment: I now realize that I didn't specify this. But what about the other way? So when saving I need to flip it back.

Comment: If you post the values to the server using form, than you can flip them back on the server side, before applying the changes to the dataBase.